# Exclude enum classes from code coverage?

Tags: java, maven, junit, jmockit, maven-surefire-plugin

Till now I'm excluding certain classes depending on their package names or class names. Is there any way I can exclude Enums like given below from coverage?

```
package com.*;

public enum Quality {
    high,normal,low;
}
```

For Coverage I'm using maven-surefire-plugin with JUnit and JMockit. And my coverage setup looks like this

```
<build>
<plugins>
....
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.18.1</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
            <artifactId>surefire-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <configuration>
        <systemPropertyVariables>
            <coverage-excludes>com.test.*,*IT.java</coverage-excludes>
        </systemPropertyVariables>
    </configuration>
</plugin>   
....
</build>
<dependencies>
    ....
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jmockit</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmockit</artifactId>
            <version>1.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jmockit</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmockit-coverage</artifactId>
            <version>1.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
        </dependency>
    ....    
  </dependencies>
```

Comment: why do you want to exclude enum? surely if some of your production code uses these enum, they will be covered otherwise it gives you an indication that a certain value is not used.

Answer (score 1):

The exclusion property accepts a regular expression. You can follow a code convention in your application such that all enums have a common pattern in their name such as QualityEnum.java, then you can apply a regex filter in the exclude

```
<exclude>%regex[*Enum.java], com.test.*</exclude>
```

Make sure other non-enum classes avoid this convention. Alternately, have a dedicated sub-package in each module for enums, and exclude the sub-package

Comment: yes I can do this. But I want to exclude depending on it's content not name post-fix.What if I want to exclude,let's say, abstract classes,introduce another post fix pattern?but good suggestion!

Comment: I would assume this would involve writing a new exclude filter implementation for surefire, that could do InstanceOf operations @mavi